# Consider $X_1(\omega)t^2+X_2(\omega)t+X_1=0$. Show that the collection of $\omega$ such that this equation has two real zeros is in a sigma-algebra.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

There's actually two parts to this question, and I'm varying degrees of stuck on each part.

(1) Let $X_1,X_2, X_3$ be random variables on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$.

Consider $X_1(\omega)t^2+X_2(\omega)t+X_1=0$. Show that $$A=\{\omega\in\Omega: \text{the equation has two distinct real roots}\} \in \mathcal{F}.$$

(2) Let $T_1(\omega),$ $T_2(\omega)$ denote the two roots of the above equation. Let
$$ f_i(\omega)= \begin{cases} 
      T_i(\omega) & \omega\in A \\
      0 & \omega\in A^c
   \end{cases}
T_i(\omega)$$

Show that the vector function $(f_1,f_2)$ is $\langle\mathcal{F},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\rangle$ measurable.

For part (1), I was thinking something like the following;

Fix some $t\in\mathbb{R}$. Then the functions $X(\omega)=\left(t^2X_1(\omega),tX_2(\omega),X_3(\omega)\right)$, and $F:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R},$ $F(a,b,c)=a+b+c$ are measurable and continuous respectively.

Therefore, the function $$(F \circ X)(\omega)=X_1(\omega)t^2+X_2(\omega)t+X_1$$ is measurable, and so, for fixed $t$, the set $A_t=\{\omega\in\Omega: X_1(\omega)t^2+X_2(\omega)t+X_1=0\}$ is in $\mathcal{F}$.

I'd like to then be able to say that $A=\bigcup_{t\in\mathbb{R}}A_t$ is therefore in $\mathcal{F}$. However, this set is an uncountable union, and what I would need is a countable union. Is there any way to turn my current approach into a countable union?

For part (2), I know that it's sufficient to show that each individual $f_i$ is measurable. Here's my attempt at doing that;

Let $B\in\mathcal{B}({R})$. We need to show that $f_i^{-1}(B)\in\mathcal{F}$. Write $$f_i^{-1}(B)=\left(A\cap f_i^{-1}(B)\right)\cup\left(A^c\cap f_i^{-1}(B)\right)=\left(A\cap T_i^{-1}(B)\right)\cup \left(A^c\cap 0_i^{-1}(B)\right).$$

If I could show that each $T_i$ is measurable, then I'd basically be done.

Is there some straightforward intuition I'm missing for why $T_i$ should be measurable?

Comment: Hint: part (1) - $\Delta > 0$. part (2) - $(f_1,f_2) = (0,0)1_{A^c} + (T_1,T_2)1_{A}$, By part (1) we have measurability of $A$ (hence of $A^c$, too). You can write $T_1,T_2$ in compact form using $\Delta$.

Comment: Your explanation for part (2) makes sense, so thanks for explaining that one.

Could you say another word about your hint in part (1)? I might just be misunderstanding your use of the $\Delta$ notation. It sounds like you aren't intending $\Delta$ to mean some small positive number?

Comment: no, $\Delta$ for quadratic equation $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ is given by $b^2 - 4ac$. You have two real roots iff $\Delta >0$, so in your case $X_2(\omega)^2 -4X_1(\omega)X_3(\omega) > 0$, so that $A = \{ \omega \in \Omega : X_2(\omega)^2 -4X_1(\omega)X_3(\omega) > 0 \}$ which is measurable due to $X_2^2 - 4X_1X_3$ being a measurable function

Comment: Oh, got it.
That's a much cleaner approach. Thanks for the suggestion!